# How can a web page communicate with a local rich client application

Tags: sockets, applet, communication, client-side

I need to implement a process where users punch in a few details into a web page, and have this information fired as some
sort of an event to a Java rich client application (SWING) on the same host.

One idea was perhaps implementing an applet that would initiate socket communication with a listener implemented by the SWING
application, but not sure whether this is possible at all.

This sort of puzzling piece of integration is basically a given fact. 
Essentially both the web application and the SWING one are already active and in use. 
The only missing bit is sharing info between the two, in a way that would be easy to implement. no matter how dirty.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a little confusing to the user if nothing else.

I would go one of two ways.

1. Have your rich client communicate over the network. And put whatever form you were going to have in the browser there.
2. Put your rich client into an applet.
3. Have both connect to a server somewhere (even locally), which your rich client can poll to see if the form has been filled in.

Comment: Hi, I realize I've omitted some details so am going to update the question.